# Is it possible to remove ExecutionContext and Thread allocations when using SocketAsyncEventArgs?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, allocation, asyncsocket

If you profile a simple client application that uses `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, you will notice `Thread` and `ExecutionContext` allocations.

The source of the allocations is `SocketAsyncEventArgs.StartOperationCommon` that creates a copy of the ExecutionContext with `ExecutionContext.CreateCopy()`.

`ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow` seems like a good way to suppress this allocation. However this method itself will generate allocations when ran in a new thread.

How can I avoid these allocations?

Comment: Why would you want to supress `ExecutionContext` flow?

Comment: Suppressing the `ExecutionContext` flow is only a way to avoid an allocation (`SocketAsyncEventArgs` does not copy the context when the flow is suppressed).

Comment: Why are you attempting to microbenchmark? Why is the allocation of an `ExecutionContext` so meaningful?

Comment: I want to use `SocketAsyncEventArgs` in a very latency sensitive application where GC pauses are an issue.

Comment: Are the allocations one per thread, or periodic? In other words, are you sure this is not simply the start-up cost, instead of a periodic allocation. I can understand the concern, since the whole point of SocketAsyncEventArgs is to avoid periodic allocations. If you could post a test program, I would be curious in seeing the allocations.

Comment: When `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow` is used, the allocations only happen in new threads. However, the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` callback is periodically executed in newly created threads. This question is closely related to http://goo.gl/JoFqbP.

Comment: Have you looked at using a non-GC language such as C++? It sounds like your application might not be a good fit for .NET.

Comment: You should probably use your own pool of threads, and circulate among them, if you absolutely must. Other than, if that really seems like a bottleneck, which is `very very very unlikely`, (and I'd say, you're almost definitely doing something the wrong way), you should switch back to a non-GC language.

Comment: May be you can use BeginX end EndX methods instead and run the GC in server mode to avoid pause

Comment: What are you doing with your threads? What they have to handle?

Comment: @FrankHileman Actually, the point of `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is to prevent fixing newly allocated buffers in memory - the problem you have when not using `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is memory fragmentation, not GC latency. If you just fix a buffer you created just for this one operation, you've got about 100% chance it will prevent heap compaction. And since the `Read` call can take pretty much forever, your heap(s) become crazy fragmented (our socket server reached over 99% fragmentation - gigabytes of memory free, but couldn't be reused).

Answer (score 2):

1. ***SocketAsyncEventArgs***

   ```
   public class SocketAsyncEventArgs : EventArgs, IDisposable {
   //...
   // Method called to prepare for a native async socket call.
   // This method performs the tasks common to all socket operations.
   internal void StartOperationCommon(Socket socket) {

       //...

       // Prepare execution context for callback.

       if (ExecutionContext.IsFlowSuppressed()) {    
       // This condition is what you need to pass.

           // Fast path for when flow is suppressed.

           m_Context = null;
           m_ContextCopy = null;

       } else {

           // Flow is not suppressed.

           //...

           // If there is an execution context we need
            //a fresh copy for each completion.

           if(m_Context != null) {
               m_ContextCopy = m_Context.CreateCopy();
           }
       }

       // Remember current socket.
       m_CurrentSocket = socket;
      }




       [Pure]
       public static bool IsFlowSuppressed()
       {
           return  Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextReader().IsFlowSuppressed;
       }
      //...
       }
   ```
2. ***ExecutionContext***

   ```
   [Serializable] 
   public sealed class ExecutionContext : IDisposable, ISerializable
   {
   //...
   // Misc state variables.
   private ExecutionContext m_Context;
   private ExecutionContext m_ContextCopy;
   private ContextCallback m_ExecutionCallback;
   //...

   internal struct Reader
   {
       ExecutionContext m_ec;
       //...
        public bool IsFlowSuppressed 
       {
        #if !FEATURE_CORECLR
           [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        #endif
           get { return IsNull ? false : m_ec.isFlowSuppressed; } 
       }

     } //end of Reader


   internal bool isFlowSuppressed 
      { 
       get 
       { 
           return (_flags & Flags.IsFlowSuppressed) != Flags.None; 
       }
       set
       {
           Contract.Assert(!IsPreAllocatedDefault);
           if (value)
               _flags |= Flags.IsFlowSuppressed;
           else
               _flags &= ~Flags.IsFlowSuppressed;
       }
      }


   [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required
   public static AsyncFlowControl SuppressFlow()
   {
       if (IsFlowSuppressed())
       {
           throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidOperation_CannotSupressFlowMultipleTimes"));
       }
       Contract.EndContractBlock();
       AsyncFlowControl afc = new AsyncFlowControl();
       afc.Setup();
       return afc;
   }
   //...
   }//end of ExecutionContext.
   ```
3. ***AsyncFlowControl***

   ```
   public struct AsyncFlowControl: IDisposable
   {
   private bool useEC;
   private ExecutionContext _ec;

   //... 

   [SecurityCritical]
   internal void Setup()
   {
       useEC = true;
       Thread currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
       _ec = currentThread.GetMutableExecutionContext();
       _ec.isFlowSuppressed = true;
       _thread = currentThread;
   }
   }
   ```
4. ***Thread***

   ```
   // deliberately not [serializable]
   [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
   [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(_Thread))]
   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
   public sealed class Thread : CriticalFinalizerObject, _Thread
   {

    //...

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
       internal ExecutionContext.Reader GetExecutionContextReader()
       {
           return new ExecutionContext.Reader(m_ExecutionContext);
       }
   }
   ```

The [only](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,3578bdaa17e975d5) way to set `isFlowSuppressed` to `true`, to pass the condition in the `StartOperationCommon` method, is by calling `Setup` method, and the only call to `Setup` is in `SuppressFlow` method, wich you have discussed.

> As you can see, `SuppressFlow` is the only solution.

Comment: You might want to add what `ExecutionContext` actually is, and what purpose it has. It's not there just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `SuppressFlow` doesn't allocate. It returns a [`AsyncFlowControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asyncflowcontrol), which is a `struct`. The proper solution basically is to call `SendAsync` and `ReceiveAsync` as follows:

```
public static bool SendAsyncSuppressFlow(this Socket self, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    var control = ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
    try
    {
        return self.SendAsync(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        control.Undo();
    }
}

public static bool ReceiveAsyncSuppressFlow(this Socket self, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    var control = ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow();
    try
    {
        return self.ReceiveAsync(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        control.Undo();
    }
}
```

I created these extension methods to make this a bit simpler and more explicit.

Traces with dotMemory showed that memory allocations really do go down to zero.